# How can we export Jspreadsheet to excel in community version?

Tags: angular

Exporting to excel is available in Jspreadsheet enterprise version, is there any way to do it in CE version?

I tried using xlsx npm module, but could not export it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xlsx npm module needs table id but Jspreadsheet does not provide the id for table. Here we can add parent div with id and  use that id in xlsx module.

Hope this will help you.